# How to translate JFileChooser column headers under Windows?

Tags: java, swing, localization, translation, jfilechooser

I have finalized a translation of a `JFileChooser` dialog to Dutch. In doing so I found [this resource](https://beradrian.wordpress.com/2007/07/30/internationalization-for-swing-standard-components/) very useful.

During the test of this translation, I ran into a problem that I am not able to resolve: under Windows (Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1 64-bit) the headers of the columns in detail view are not translated. It does not matter which Look & Feel I am using. When I test on Mac the headers are properly translated. Here is some code to demonstrate the problem. Switch to Details to see the column headers. I added the translation of Refresh to Verversen in the context menu to demonstrate that other translations are picked up.

```
package translationjfilechooser;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class TranslateColumnsJFileChooser {

    JFileChooser fc;

    public TranslateColumnsJFileChooser() {
        UIManager.put("FileChooser.fileNameHeaderText", "Naam");
        UIManager.put("FileChooser.fileSizeHeaderText", "Grootte");
        UIManager.put("FileChooser.fileTypeHeaderText", "Bestandstype");
        UIManager.put("FileChooser.fileDateHeaderText", "Gewijzigd op");
        UIManager.put("FileChooser.refreshActionLabelText", "Verversen");
        try {
            // It does not matter which Look & Feel you are using
            // UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Could not change look and feel");
            return;
        }
        fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.setDialogTitle("This demonstrates that column headers are not translated under Windows");
        fc.showOpenDialog(fc);
        return;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TranslateColumnsJFileChooser();
    }
}
```

Does anybody know a way to translate these headers? Or at least the reason why they cannot be translated?

In order to analyse the problem I tried to find the translation keys for these headers in the Java source code, but was not able to find them. Neither was I able to find the key `FileChooser.refreshActionLabelText`.

Comment: This appears to be fixed in Java 11.

Comment: I thought Java supports the Dutch (Netherlands) **Locale**.

Comment: @DevilsHnd, java 8 supports many locales, but only a few translations, see https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/java8locales-2095355.html#translation. Java 11 only support 3 translations: English, Japanese and Chinese (Simplified)

Comment: @VGR, I am not able to upgrade to Java 11 now. I will do as soon as possible and report back if that solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm it is fixed in Java 11 as [VGR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1831987/vgr) posted in the comments.